# Expanding and resizing div

Tags: css, html, web-applications

I have a 4x4 grid of div's setup. I wanna make it so when I click on a div it expands and is resizable. Like its on private window within the browser window. And when I double click it I want it to snap back into its original small square shape back in the grid line up

Comment: solved it or still looking for solution?

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of your desired outcome or a similar working effect? It's not clear how you want it to behave and how the other elements are affected. P.S heard of lightbox?

Comment: @mike still looking for my solution but aziz has me on the right track

Answer (score 0, accepted):

User `toggleClass()`.
Here is the working **[Codepen](http://codepen.io/creativemind1/pen/jqJzvY)**

```
$('#dude').on('click', function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('expand');
});
```

Comment: would this go into css or html window? sorry if my question is noob but I'm learning as I'm going. i see the css brackets in there so it kind of threw me off

Comment: That is JavaScript code, specifically jQuery - it can be inside the HTML within a `<script>` tag or externally in a `.js` file. Please note that if you want jQuery code, you will need to include the jQuery library - see jquery.com

Comment: ohh ok i see it in the codepen. it expands like i want but once expanded i want it to be resizable to make room for the other div. think like widows phone software layout but more symmetrical and customizable regarding the boxes